# Sigma Field Question

Tags: probability-theory

I am currently studying for my intro to probability test tomorrow. I am pumping out practice problems, yet there is one that has stumped me and I can't find the answer. I was wondering if anyone would care to help?

Let $S = \{x ∈ R : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1\}$ be a sample space. Let $A$ be the collection of all finite subsets of $S$, and
$B$ be the collection of all subsets of $S$ that have finite complements. Is $A \cup B$ a sigma-field? Why or why
not?

Comment: What is the definition of a $\sigma$-field? Which axioms do you think are satisfied, and why?

Comment: Probabilists call $\sigma$-algebras by $\sigma$-fields.

Comment: Well, my intuition is that they are all satisfied. The empty set and the whole set should be in there, and the axiom that states if a set is in, its complement is in too is also satisfied. However, I don't know about the last axiom of sigma fields, can't tell if that is satisfied. Also, I know uncountable sets usually cause problems, so I am not sure how that should effect this problem

Comment: The last axiom says that the union of a sequence of sets $C_n$ in the $\sigma$-field is also in the $\sigma$-field. If one of the $C_n$'s is in $B$, could that be a problem? (No, but say why.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the sets $S_n=\{\tfrac1n\}$ and $S=\bigcup S_n$. Do you think that either $S\in A$ or $S\in B$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu$ be be counting measure and $S=[0,1]$.

$\mathcal{A} = \{ A: A\subset S, \mu(A) < \infty \} $ and

$\mathcal{B} = \{A\:: A^c \in \mathcal{A} \}$.

Claim:  $\Omega:=\mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B}$ is a sigma-algebra (field).

1)  $\mu(\emptyset)=0 \implies \emptyset \in  \mathcal{A}\subset \Omega$

2a) If $A\in \Omega$ such that  $\mu(A)<\infty$ then $(A^c)^c = A \in \mathcal{A} \implies A^c \in \mathcal{B} \subset \Omega$.

2b) If $A\in \Omega$ such that $\mu(A)= \infty$ then $A \not \in \mathcal{A}$ so $A \in \mathcal{B}$ hence (by definition) $A^c \in \mathcal{A} \subset \Omega$.

3) You may start writing this (I did...)

If $A_1, A_2 ,... \in \Omega$ then may rewrite this list as $A_{a_1},A_{a_2},... \in\mathcal{A}$ and $A_{b_1},A_{b_2},... \in \mathcal{B}$.

BUT

COUNTEREXAMPLE....

Let $Q=\mathbb{Q}\cap S$ then $\mu(q)=1$ for every $q\in Q$ but $\mu(Q) = \mu(\bigcup_{q\in Q} q) = \sum_{q\in Q} \mu(q) =\sum_{q\in Q} 1= \infty$ and

$\mu(Q^c) = \mu(\text{Irrationals of S}) =\infty$.

Comment: FYI, the counting measure $\mu$ is just the function that tells us how many elements are in a set, so for example, $\mu(\{0, 4, \pi ,73 \}) = 4$ but $\mu(2\mathbb{N})=\infty.$